# InDesign master pages and modifying placeholder text style

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page, paragraph-styles

I have a master page set up in my book and it has a text box to act as placeholder text. This is to be common headers used throughout the book.

All I want to do is to reduce the font size, but changing it in the master page doesn't take any affect. The font remains large on the style source document and the rest of the docs in the book. I've adjusted the font itself and tried applying a paragraph style.

[image: apply paragraph style]

But this has no affect. The font is still large on all pages.

Maybe I did this wrong - to apply the headings to each document, I Ctrl + Shift + Click on the placeholder text and use the text tool to enter each heading. Maybe that's incorrect?

EDIT: I just noticed 2 strange things:

1) If I remove and re-apply the A-Header master page to a document and redo the text, it does follow the new formatting. But that's rough because there's a lot of them, I'd have to redo them all manually. Blah.

2) I can go to any page and edit the master page text freely, without having to ctrl+shift+click. So it's almost acting like it's free text and not from a master page. *This may be what the issue is* but I'm not sure why/how that happened.

Comment: How did applying a paragraph style not work? Changing the style ought to have changed all headings in your document (unless you already overrode the size manually).

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure. I created an edit above that may help clarify what the real issue is.